# Is there a way to measure the complexity of a language?

Tags: language-agnostic, computer-science

When I embark on learning a new language (like Java) or a system (like git) it would be very helpful to get an idea of the overall size of the mountain I've got to climb.

Is there some way of measuring code in this way?

E.g. you can measure the height of a mountain and the difficulty of the ascent. Is there something similar for code?

UPDATE

This went some way towards answering what I wanted to know: http://redmonk.com/dberkholz/2013/03/25/programming-languages-ranked-by-expressiveness/

Comment: "*Is there something similar for code?*"  Clarification, you are not asking about how to measure the complexity of "code" (for which some tools do exist), but rather of a language, for which, unfortunately, there are only some questionable academic theories, and a whole ton of personal opinions (which you will get a lot of).

Answer (score 0):

Not easily. You'd probably be best to just do a few searches - you are likely to find people saying things like HTML is fairly simple and C++ is hard, though I understand this is not a reliable method.
Ultimately, how hard something is to learn varies a lot between individuals and a languages similarity to what you already know is also likely to have an impact.

If it helps, some general rules I have noticed are as follows:

- Fully interpreted languages such as JavaScript and Python are very relaxed about variable types, which can make them easier to learn.
- C based languages (C, C++, Java, etc.) all have very similar syntax, if you can program one, the others shouldn't be too hard learn.
- Languages like Python are designed to read like human speech, this can make them far easier to understand, though they are often very different from other languages and can occasionally be inconsistent.
- More traditional compiled languages like C and C++ are generally very strict on syntax (but flexible with formatting) which can give them a steeper learning curve, but I would recommend them to a beginner as once you are used to strict syntax, it is easy to adapt to less strict syntax than vice versa.